# Filesystem resource failed, Error=timeout during failover resource on pacemaker cluster

Tags: linux, redhat, pacemaker, drbd

I try to setup NFS Active/passive + DRBD on Pacemaker cluster.
When i start cluster for the first time every things is ok but when i shutdown master node, resource move to another node but failed on Filesystem resource.

that is status of resource when i start the cluster.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2GUc.png)

and the next capture correspond at cluster status when resource try to failover after shutdown or restart the master node

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaY8F.png)

You can see my resource config

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3rJl.png)

Constraints

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoLr1.png)

please can someone help me

Comment: Do not post images, or links to images. Please edit the question & with the actual text.